# How to subtact a Sum Amount from my table a from a value in my table b

Tags: sql-server

**tableA**:

```
tranactionid staffid amount 
1001          19052   2000
1002          19043   3000
1004          19076   4000
```

**tableB**:

```
BudgetCode Budget
271098     20000
```

I want to sum `Amount` in `tableA` and subtract it from `Budget` value 20000

```
20000 - 9000 = 11000
```

Comment: this is my sql statement:  select (SELECT Budget AS Total1 from tableB) - (SELCT SUM(amount) AS Total2 From tableA) AS Result

Comment: Don't try to put code in a comment.   Edit your post instead.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?  Your SQL query seems to work fine, except for the typo `SELCT` (but as @TabAlleman said, it should be edited into your post, not posted as a comment).

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
 SELECT (SELECT [Budget] FROM tableB) - (SELECT SUM([amount]) FROM tableA) AS [any_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if TableB has just one row forever, but it's likely your requirements go beyond that:

```
SELECT tableB.Budget - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tableA)
FROM tableB.Budget;
```